# XML Feed Parsing Plugin

Tags: plugins

Are there any plugins like this Expression Engine feed parser?

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/feed-parser

Temporarily cache an XML file from a website or API and list the results using standard Twig templating tags.

Comment: Just finished off our plugin for this, feel free to try it out. Feedback very welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

We're actually working on a plugin for just this at the moment for one of our projects. It's more for populating channels from a feed (like Solspace Importer or DataGrab), but exposing this via a template tag is something we'll look at including.

Interested if anyone else has come across anything though!

**Edit:** [Feed Me](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe) plugin added.